# probability of summation of 4 random variables

Tags: random-variables

i have this question here;

> Let X1, X2, X3, X4 be random variables that are all independent of
> each other and have the same distribution, namely, P(X1 = 1) = 0.2,
> P(X1 = 0) = 0.8, and identically so for X2, X3, X4. Calculate the
> probability that P(X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 <= 3).

My calculation as such.
n = 4, p = 0.2, x <=3
Using binomial formula, the probability distribution is as such
x = 0, 0.4096
x = 1, 0.4096
x = 2, 0.1536
x = 3, 0.0256
x = 4, 0.0016
Adding x = 3 and below, total probability for P(X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 <= 3) is **0.9984**

Is 0.9984 correct?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Could you please add an edit to your question explaining how you arrived at the answer you stated / your ideas and attempts at this problem?

Comment: Under what circumstances, zero, can the sum of the four variables fail to be less than or equal to $3$?

Comment: Are you still here, zero?

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed.  Alternatively you could use the rule of complementary events.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(S\leq 3) &=1-\mathsf P(S=4) \\ &=1-(0.2)^4 \\ &= 0.9984\end{align}$$

---

Where $S$ is the sum of the four iid random variables.